# Iterating through a list of elements and removing the cursor style on them based on inner text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of divs in the following structure, where the text in the `a.status-progress` will either say "in progress" or "not started":

```
<div class="plan-section">
    <div class="tableView-row">
        <p class="plan-name">
            <a>some name</a>
         </p>
         <a class="status-progress">in progress</a>
     </div>
</div>
<!-- same structure as above but not expanded -->
<div class="plan-section"></div>
<div class="plan-section"></div>
```

All the `<a>` tags with in each `<div>` act as links. What I would like to do is loop through each div, check and see if the `a.progress` has the string "in progress" with in it . If it doesn't I want to remove the `cursor:pointer` css property and any events attached to the `<a>` tags. Current my jQuery implementation is:

```
// remove linking if plan is not joined
$('.status-progress').each(function(i){
    var planLinks = $('.status-progress, .plan-name a');
    var planStatus = $(this).text();
    if (planStatus === "in progress"){
            planLinks.css('cursor','pointer')
        }
    });
```

This is not working properly though because I believe my logic with the `each()` is wrong or that I need to add another one later in the code block. Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Added proper class for status-progress

Comment: Where is `.status-progress`?

Comment: Sorry, made an edit to update the html with the proper class, it's the element that contains the "in progress text".

Comment: I would think it would be a much better approach to just assign a class to one of the parent elements indicating in progress.  Then you can not only style accordingly but also have a handle to key off of rather than trying to read the text of a child element.

Comment: This is true, I would still need to loop through it to assign the class to the parent based on the inner text of the 'a.status-progress' in theory right?

Comment: I think Joseph meant that the class should be assigned by the same code that added the 'in progress' text in the first place.

Comment: Actually you are right, this is a good implementation. And the route I think I will choose so that I don't need to implement more Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
var planLinks = $('.status-progress, .plan-name a');
```

...will select *all* such anchor elements, not just the ones related to the current iteration of the `.each()` loop. One way to get just the related ones is:

```
var planLinks = $(this).closest("div").find("a");
```

That is, use DOM traversal methods to find the containing div and then select the anchors within it. Or you could go based on siblings, etc., but that is more fragile since a change to the html structure is then more likely to require a change to the JS.

But you don't really need the `.each()` loop if you do something like this instead:

```
$("a.status-progress:contains('in progress')")   // find the 'in progress' anchors
                .closest("div")                  // get their containing divs
                .find("a")                       // find the anchors in those divs
                .off()                           // remove the event handlers
                .css('cursor','pointer');        // set the CSS property
```

Comment: This worked, I ended up choosing a different approach but will give the answer to you since it did solve the problem I had asked. Thanks!